# NovaCode DocX - Line Spacing

Tags: .net, vb.net, novacode-docx

I am working with Novacode DocX and using this same code over 2 different projects products 2 different results.

```
Dim customerAddress = doc.InsertParagraph(SetCustomerAddress(recipient))
customerAddress.Alignment = Alignment.left
customerAddress.SetLineSpacing(LineSpacingTypeAuto.None)


Private Shared Function SetCustomerAddress(recipient As String) As String

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.AppendLine(recipient)
    For Each line In RecipientAddress
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then
            sb.AppendLine(line.Trim())

        End If
    Next

    Return sb.ToString()

End Function
```

In the one word document it produces the text with no additional lines between, and the other with a space between each line.

I have checked the output in the watch window when debugging and it is being produced as I expect. Its only when I get into the Word Document is there an issue.

Any and all help greatly received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After building new documents with this and having the same issue, I went back a version from 1.0.0.22 to 1.0.0.19 and the issue went away.

For anyone that stumbles across this issue in the future then try dropping down to version 1.0.0.19

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain the discrepancy. One thing you could try is something like this;

```
    var p = Doc.InsertParagraph(text, false, GetHeadlineFormat());
    p.LineSpacingBefore = 6;
    p.LineSpacingAfter = 1;
```

Comment: it must be something that I am doing but i cannot see what. I am out of the office at the moment but will try it when i get back in thank you for the response. I will let you know how i get on

Comment: How did you get on?

Comment: I found the issue, something changed between version 1.0.0.19 and 1.0.0.22 which is whats causing the issue